# In SQL, is there something like COALESCE() to qualify Column values which are NOT NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an `"Order"Table which houses "Status"Column. Values under Status = ('Completed','Sold','In-Process','Released','NotStarted')`.

Even though there is no sequence or hierarchy for that in the table, we can perceive the sequence as below.

```
1   NotStarted
2   Released
3   In-Process
4   Sold
5   Completed
```

So 'Completed' is the highest status and each order goes through these Statuses until they are Completed. if they are not completed yet, they should be in one of the other status.

When I filter on Completed, I miss out on the other records. When I include all Status, I get multiple records of same order such as 1 record for Released, 1 record for InProcess, etc (i.e, the various stages of the order)

```
select * from OrderTable
where Status = 'Completed'
```

I want to have the ability to do something like this --
`COALESCE(Completed,Sold,In-Process,Released,NotStarted, NULL)`

In other words, I want to get the highest record for that status and only 1 record for each order.

Is this possible in Sql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with a Case expression to establish your ordering.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
       SELECT OrderNumber,
        Status,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNumber ORDER BY 
                           CASE Status 
                               WHEN 'NotStarted' THEN 1
                               WHEN 'Released' THEN 2
                               WHEN 'In-Process' THEN 3
                               WHEN 'Sold' THEN 4
                               WHEN 'Completed' THEN 5 
                               END DESC) as Order_Status_Rank
        FROM OrderTable
    ) dt
WHERE Order_Status_Rank = 1;
```

[See it in action here](https://rextester.com/NLXJ6002)

Comment: Beat me to it! I was literally typing out the windowing function when your answer popped up.

Comment: I got a head start when Gordon slowed the crowd down with the RDBMS question in the comments ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer...I am just understanding the Row Number() function and testing it out for my data and will let you know soon if it worked for me. Cheers.

Comment: That `ROW_NUMBER()` function is part of a group of functions called "Window Functions". Basically you apply a window function to a "Partition" or group of records. You define what that group is as part of the function's statement. Here it's `PARTITION BY OrderNumber` because we want to treat the group of records with the same order number as a partition, we then order them by the result of the CASE expression and it will then apply the `ROW_NUMBER()` (counting from 1 to whatever) until it hits the end of that group/partition starting over at 1 with the next partition. They are VERY useful.

Comment: Thanks @JNevill for helping me understand this concept in Sql.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the numbers shown in your list instead of the text, all you would have to do is select Top 1 and sort on the number.  You can use another table to store the number/entry data.  By the way, this would also prevent erroneous data entry.